# (Java) Unable to catch an Exception

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I'm a beginner with Java and was attempting to catch the exception 'InputMismatchException'. Below is my code, I hope it is easy to read, apologies in advance if it's not formatted well. It builds fine and executes, but if I input a character for example the 'catch' doesn't function and the error comes up;

"Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException"

I believe everything else in the code works fine including the 'try', and I don't have anything going in the catch other than a System.out.print command.

```
import java.util.*; // imports

public class w4q1

    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in ); // declaring Scanner util
                System.out.print("Please enter an integer: \n"); // Asks for input
                int d = user_input.nextInt();

        while (d > 0 || d < 0) // start of while loop, in the event of anything other than zero entered
        {
            try {

                    if (d < 0) // if statements
                    {
                    System.out.print("The integer " + d + " is negative\n");
                    break;
                    }

                            else if (d > 0)
                            {
                            System.out.print("The integer " + d + " is positive\n");
                            break;
                            }

                                else 
                                {
                                System.out.print("You have not entered an integer\n");
                                break;
                                }

                }

                catch (InputMismatchException e) // Error message for letters/characters and decimals
                    {
                        System.out.print("You have entered an incorrect value, please restart the program\n");
                    }



        }

        if (d == 0)
            {
            System.out.print("A zero has been entered\n");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: `int d = user_input.nextInt();` should be inside the `try` block.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still receiving an `InputMismatchException` even though you have a try-catch block, then the exception must be coming from somewhere outside of your try-catch block.

Look at what else outside the try-catch block can throw an `InputMismatchException` and put a try-catch block around that statement, or expand your existing try-catch block to include that statement.

Comment: Ahh you're right I think, I have the user_input.nextInt outside the try block which is causing it not to catch. Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 0):

If indeed the exception is not getting caught, then the resulting stack trace should show you the actual line of code which threw the exception. Looking at the code, I'm going to guess that this is where the exception occurs:

```
 user_input.nextInt();
```

I would recommend you look at the stack trace and see if you can confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

Put a try-catch block around this code

> int d = user_input.nextInt();

and by so doing ,you also need to change the current code a little bit  to make it OK. Good Luck !